# Resample 2d coordinates with values in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame in pandas containing x coordinates, y coordinates, and values.
I would like to "downsample" my coordinates and add the values appropriately.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                   'y': [1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4], 
                   'v': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1] })
```

Visualizing this data frame with a scatter plot looks like:

[image]

and I want to resample my data to something like this:
[image]

The v values should simply be added together.
I also would like to choose the factor of the sampling.

I first looked into df.resample but this only applies to time series data. I assume this can be achieved with groupby() somehow but it seems I just can't figure it out. Any hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: i don't understand how you want to group your data but did you try something like df.groupby(['x']).sum() or  df.groupby(['x','y']).sum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
g = df.groupby([df.x.sub(1) // 2 * 2 + 1.5,
                df.y.sub(1) // 2 * 2 + 1.5])
g.v.sum().reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!